# NestJS: How to union, combine select result of createQueryBuilder?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have this two `createQueryBuilder`, table structure is the same but different source, How can I possibly return it like `Union All` in sql?

Code:

```
    async getActivityPostArticle() {
    const query = this.repoActivityPost
      .createQueryBuilder('activity')
      .select('activity.*, article.*')
      .innerJoin(
        'activity_article',
        'article',
        'article.id::text = activity.post_id::text',
      );

      const query2 = this.repoActivityPost
      .createQueryBuilder('activity')
      .select('activity.*, newsfeed.*')
      .innerJoin(
        'activity_newsfeed',
        'newsfeed',
        'newsfeed.id::text = activity.post_id::text',
      );

    return query.getRawMany();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in method for UNION however you can do this

```
const result = await entityManager.query(`${ query.getQuery() } UNION ${ query2.getQuery() }`);
```